# USB external hard drive suddenly refuses to mount?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, disk-utility

I am unable (as of today) to access an external hard-drive (The USB variant). It does not or will not show under my Devices directory in Finder. If I open `Disk Utility`, the application will forever tell me it is loading the drives unless I unplug the external and plug it in after opening the application (at which point it shows nothing).

I then tried running `diskutil` in the terminal to see if the drive was being recognized somewhere. And it is, kind of:

```
CXR-MBP13:~ Owatch$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 BFDF1A89-7E29-4DEE-92E8-143DA7D4563C
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS CXExternal              500.1 GB   disk2s1
```

It's listed as `disk2s1`. My external is named **CXExternal**.

I tried running `verifyVolume` on the drive to see if it could tell me anything:

```
CXR-MBP13:~ Owatch$ diskutil verifyVolume CXExternal
Started file system verification on disk2s1 CXExternal
Verifying file system
File system check exit code is 8
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
```

I cannot seem to do any more than this. I thought perhaps I should be using `verifyDisk` and tried that, but nothing seems to get me anywhere. What can I do apple.stackexchange? I want to be able to access this external. You're my only hope.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? If you do, have you backed up your data/is the data on that drive unimportant?

Comment: @MythicCocoa The problem was never solved. The data was recovered via accessing the drive through Ubuntu, which could mount it for some reason. It was never possible to fix the issue on macOS though. So I have not marked it solved as the problem was never truly solved that way. Maybe someone will post something eventually which would help others searching for this specific problem.

Comment: Try to reformat the disk